# Stack Overflow Careers reminder email: days left until invitation expires do not agree

Tags: bug, jobs, email

I got an email this morning reminding me I still have not yet joined Stack Overflow Careers.

At the outset, the email said I have only three days remaining until this invitation expires, but later on says there are 14 days remaining.  My guess is the latter number is baked into the text.

[image]

Comment: The second one should probably read "within" 14 days

Comment: @Pekka웃 no, it should probably read "soon".

Comment: Yeah, true. It doesn't really matter what the original period was.